# Vb6 project compilation without a specific DLL reference

Tags: vb6

I need to compile a Vb6 project, using the CMD console. Compilation must be done by disabling a DLL before compiling. My sentence is as follows `Vb6 /m /out File.vb`.

In the attached image, you can see how it is done through the VB6 interface. For this compilation I require to do the same when the project is going to be compiled, but from the command line.

[image]

I really appreciate the help you can give me.

Thansks a lot for your responses. I'm going to explain again the problem...
From command line I need to compile two projects (This projects create DLLs not an exe file) A.vbp and B.vbp. The B.vbp project has configured a reference to the dll that is created when a.vbp is compiled. So when A.vbp is compiled the new dll is generated, but the reference in B.vbp is lost so the reference has to be created again to be able to compile B.vbp. When I use the VB6 IDE, no problem, but I need to do it from command line and I don't know how to add the reference to the dll that is created when A.vbp is compiled to successfully compile B.vbp.  I attach an image of the project in VB6 and I hope it will be useful to understand the scenario.
The commands lines are vb6.exe /m /out errors.txt A.vbp (Sucessfully compiled) and vb6.exe /m /out errors.txt B.vbb (Compilation error caused by dll reference)
Best regards and thanks for your attention and suggestions.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtVZE.png)

Comment: Just to clarify:  before compiling through the IDE you go to the References window and uncheck items?

Comment: This has indications of an XY question (eg, if you don't need the references to compile, then you also don't need them in the IDE, so you can remove them forever). But to address the question, you can't change those via a command line compile. You can have two separate and otherwise identical .vbp files, one with the references, one without, use the latter for command line compile.

Comment: Also - the compile command is wrong, it's missing the project filename, and the output filename of 'File.vb' makes no sense.

Comment: Hello everyone and thank you very much for your responses
Yes I forgot mention the output exe file Sorry
SolutionXYZ.vbg
    -- Project One.vbp, that among other DLLs, generate One.dll
    -- Project Two.vbp  ==> References One.dll
In order to generate some required DLLs included One.dll, from One.vbp project, I need to disable that reference in Two.vbp project. After doing this, I go to the One.vbp project and compile it. Then I have to enable One.dll reference (in Two.vbp project) before build it. 
I need to do that true command line task in Azure DevOps Server as a part of a pipeline.

Comment: The `.vb` file extension is not used by VB6, that is VB.NET (which is a different language / compiler / IDE / etc.)

Comment: @Audberto please edit the question to update with more information. Comments are not very readable for lots of information. Thanks

Comment: Regarding the description added in comments by OP (by the way, as already suggested, please place this information in the post, not comments), although it's difficult to tell from the description, it sounds like you should consider configuring the 'One.dll' to use binary compatibility, which would mean the 'old' references to it would still be accurate and usable. This assumes, of course, that the interface for that dll isn't changing frequently (which if it is, is usually a different kind of bad idea).